# Verificar se um certo valor se encontra no vector

Tags: array, matlab, vector

Criei o vector `fragil` que vai aceitar vários inputs do utilizador, inputs estes que vão (ou não) ser a posição de outros elementos numa outra matriz. Usei a seguinte função para criar o vector `fragil`:

```
fragil = zeros(1, numIdosos);
```

E de seguida queria verificar no segundo `if` do excerto abaixo se o `j` pertence ao vector `fragil`. Ou seja, existe alguma maneira de verificar se o `j` pertence ao vector `fragil` sem adicionar o `for` extra que percorre o vector `fragil` todo?

```
for j=1:numIdosos
     if MCobertura(iMax,j)==1
             contador(j)=contador(j)+1;
     end
     if contador (j)>1 
         porCobrir(j)=0;
     end
 end
 n_porCobrir=sum(porCobrir);
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) para retornar o índice caso o número que procura exista dentro do vetor:

```
x = [1     3     5     7     9    11    13    15    17    19]

k = find(x==3);

if isempty(k)

    disp('nao achei')

else

    disp('achei')

end
```

No exemplo acima estou usando o `find` para procurar a ocorrência do número `3` dentro do vetor `x`, se encontrar ele colocará o índice dentro da variável `k`, após isso eu comparo com o `if` se houve retorno ou não, se a variável `k` estiver vazia não existe ocorrência do número que procura no vetor.